# Stop exoplayer from downloading next chunk of data when no network is detected

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I'm using exoplayer 2.8.2 and if I play a regular HLS stream and turn on airplane mode I will get an internal error(not user facing) that the exoPlayer has encountered a playback error, (no network connection or host is unresolved due to no network connection) Is it possible to stop the exoplayer from requesting more data from the hls stream if I know midstream that the user has no network connectivity?